# Related ids per row in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

Given the following table with two columns:

```
ID  ACC

A1  ACC1
A2  ACC1
A3  ACC1
B1  ACC2
B2  ACC2
```

All rows are related based on the ACC column. So my goal is to have the following table:

```
ID  ID2  ACC

A1  A2   ACC1
A1  A3   ACC1
A2  A1   ACC1
A2  A3   ACC1
A3  A1   ACC1
A3  A2   ACC1
B1  B2   ACC2
B2  B1   ACC2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
select left.ID, rigth.ID, left.ACC
from have as left, have as right
where left.ACC eq right.ACC
and left.ID ne right.ID;
quit;
```